# modify separator values in a df R

Tags: r, dataframe, separator

I need to modify the separator in col1 and col2 of the following df :

```
       col1                              col2           col3
12     7LOP                               no            Z;A
13     6WPS    I;J;K;M;O;P;Q;R;T;U;V;W;N;S;X          A;B;E
14     6WPT           F;G;IK;M;N;O;P;Q;R;J;D          A;B;C
15     7L0N                              G;I            E;F
```

I need to replace ";" with "," and each letter needs to have quotes. so for example col3 of the first rows should become "Z","A"

I need to do this because after I have to build a vector with each element contained in col3. I'm working in a loop and I have:

```
 library(bio3d)
    files <- df$col1
    chain <- df$col3
    
    for (i in 1:length(files){
    pdb <- read.pdb(paste0(files[i], ".pdb"))
    pdb <- atom.select(pdb, chain = c(## HERE I NEED TO PUT LETTERS CONTAINED IN col3))
    ...     #other stuff 
    }
```

How I can do? Thanks!

Comment: The letters already have quotes but the print method doesn't show them. As for the other question, `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) gsub(";", ",", x, fixed = TRUE))`.

Comment: pls read my update, thanks

Comment: We need some more clarity about your desired output, please. `ss <- strsplit(df$col3, sep=";")` will give you a list of vectors ... `ss[[1]]` is equivalent to your `myvec` above.

Comment: Do you want to paste *both* `"Z"` and `"A"` with `col1`?

Comment: check now if it's more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to add quotes then you could do it this way

```
lapply(df$col2, function(x){paste0('"',gsub(";",'","',x),'"')})
```

Comment: this returns me a list, pls check the updated question

Comment: can you please provide a `dput(df)` of your dataframe?